# Heroku Cron: How to find the cron schedule?

Tags: cron, heroku

If I log into the Heroku site and view my Cron add-on, Heroku will show me:

1. the next time cron is scheduled to run, and
2. the last time cron ran.

Is there a way to query this info via heroku CLI (or cleanly obtain this via some other way programatically?)

Thx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

heroku info via cli will give you the last run and next run time